# How to switch manifest with "repo init -m"

Tags: android, repository

I'm using repo to build Android. I want to build from a previous release (e.g. build #1234 from last month). I do something like this:

I start with a special copy of the manifest that explicitly sets the revision for each package:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  ...
  <project name="packages/apps/Browser" revision="f42301ffb36a68fadffdb87fa1bdc09aceac53cb"/>
  <project name="packages/apps/Calculator" revision="481a23ed78397e35201de3638ec0d76797b77d25"/>
  <project name="packages/apps/Calendar" revision="19a0737be4d51aa71a0d122f5f24ab7e53869398"/>
  <project name="packages/apps/Camera" revision="67e6c190f82f0f7b8704fe5663eb92082c4cc943"/>
  ...
</manifest>
```

This is basically a copy of default.xml, but with the revision for each package specified explicitly for the commit that was in place when build #1234 was created.

So now I give the commands

```
cp ~/manifest-build-1234.xml .repo/manifests
repo init -m manifest-build-1234.xml
repo sync
```

The result: *Some* of the packages are set to the revision specified in the manifest, but some of the others remain at the previous head.

If I delete those packages entirely, and then do another `repo sync`, then the packages are checked out at the correct revision.

So my question is: short of just deleting everything before I do the `repo sync`, how can I guarantee that all packages are checked out at the correct revision?

Comment: Ahhh, big hint: Any project that's in a "detached HEAD" state is synchronized properly. Any project for which I'm actually on a named branch stays on that branch.

Comment: Okay then just run "repo abandon <branch_name> " before you start "repo sync". It's just a workaround. I am not sure about whats happening in your case.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. Is "repo abandon" the inverse of "repo start"?

Comment: Yes it is. It deletes branch named <branch_name>.

Comment: Use --trace with repo command to check what steps get executed while running repo commands. e.g "repo --trace sync -j4"

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. This is all so frustrating. I was doing some work yesterday, and all my "repo uploads" failed at first, because I'd forgotten that I'd done "repo abandon" last week. It's easy enough to fix, but those little glitches in my workflow are so annoying.

Comment: @mrutyunjay, make your comment an answer, and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use --trace with repo command to check what steps get executed while running repo commands. e.g "repo --trace sync -j4"

Comment: Actually, it was the "repo abandon" comment that fixed my problem.